# Run jmockit in intelijIdea

Tags: maven, spring-boot, intellij-idea, jmockit

I have setup my spring boot project with `jmockit 1.43` and `spring boot 2.0.1` in InteliJIdea. I have written some test cases using jmockit expectations. I was able to run the test case from the command line but not from the intelij idea. Idea prints following error in the console.

> at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:190)
>     at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)   at
>   com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
>     at
>   com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
>     at
>   com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
>     at
>   com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
>   Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: JMockit didn't get
>   initialized; please check the -javaagent JVM initialization parameter
>   was used  at
>   mockit.internal.startup.Startup.verifyInitialization(Startup.java:91)
>     at mockit.Invocations.(Invocations.java:25)     ... 32 more

Answer (score 7):

Guess you need to set the "`-javaagent`" flag to your configuration...

See: http://jmockit.github.io/tutorial/Introduction.html#runningTests

***Run Config in IntelliJ:***

[image]

Comment: My console logs "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\bin\java.exe" `-javaagent:C:rep\.m2\repository/org/jmockit/jmockit/1.43/jmockit-1.43.jar` -Didea.test.cyclic.buffer.size=10485760 "-javaagent:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2018.2.3\lib\idea_rt.jar=59862:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition .... looks like -javaagent has been configured.

Comment: Note to self: Make sure you declare it as VM Parameters inside the Run Configuration dialog instead of the Command Line Parameters! The VM Options can be shown in the current IntelliJ versions via "Modify Options" and "Add VM Options".

Comment: Thanks so much, I couldn't find this, was searching from long time. After adding -javaagent with jmockit.jar it worked